# Format String in Swift

Tags: ios, string, swift, watchkit

I have a String saved in an NSDictionary named `accountInfoDict` that I received from my iPhone app.  I want to show this string using Swift in my watch kit app.

This is how I am trying to display the string:

```
self.pointsLabel.setText(String(format: "%@ points",
arguments: accountInfoDict!["points"] as? String))
```

I get an error message saying:

> Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type '[CVarArgType]'

Does anyone know what this means and how I can format my string to make this work?  Thanks!

**Note:**

The string displays correctly when I do it like this:

```
self.pointsLabel.setText(accountInfoDict!["points"] as? String)
```

But I want to add "points" to the end of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just achieve it by writing it like:

```
// If point is nil, shows 0
let point = accountInfoDict!["points"] as? String ?? "0"
self.pointsLabel.setText("\(point) Points")
```

Also you can write it as:

```
self.pointsLabel.setText(String(format: "%@ points", arguments: [point]))
```

More conveniently:

```
self.pointsLabel.setText(String(format: "%@ points", point))
```

Answer (score 1):

Break it into 2 lines:

```
let points = accountInfoDict!["points"] as! String
self.pointsLabel.setText(String(format: "%@ points",points))
```

You can also usestring interpolation in Swift:

```
self.pointsLabel.setText("\(accountInfoDict!["points"]!) points")
```